# Translate and sort French date php

Tags: php

I have an array with dates to convert into date and sort them.
Here is the string extracted from the array : **Samedi 14 janvier 2017 - 13h45**

I've started to delete the hour :

```
$only_date = strstr(strtolower($date),' - ', true);
```

The result is : **Samedi 14 janvier 2017**

Then I tried to convert it :

```
strftime(" %A %B %Y",strtotime($only_date));
```

But it doesn't work, I obtain 01-01-1970.

How can I handle this?

Thanks.

EDIT :

I removed the week day :

```
$days = array('lundi','mardi','mercredi','jeudi','vendredi','samedi','dimanche');
$only_date = str_replace($days,"",$date_string);
echo strftime(" %A %B %Y",strtotime($only_date));
```

And I obtain : jeudi Janvier 1970 (Thursday January 1970)

Comment: I think you should remove the weekname as well. This should be it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It doesn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've edited my first post.

Comment: I meant the weekname not the day. The `$only_date` should look like this: `14 janvier 2017`

Comment: Furthermore you should replace the month names with english ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the string and converting it to date would solve the problem. Here is a function which might help you.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

function convert_date($date) {
  $date_arr = explode(" ",$date);
  $time = explode("h",$date_arr[5]);
  $months = array("janvier","février","mars","avril","mai","juin","juillet","août","septembre","octobre","novembre","décembre");
  return date('c',mktime($time[0],$time[1],0,array_search($date_arr[2], $months)+1,$date_arr[1],$date_arr[3]));
}

$date = "Samedi 14 janvier 2017 - 13h45";
echo convert_date($date);
?>
```

Here is a piece of code to sort the date array.

```
$date_arr[0] = convert_date("Samedi 14 janvier 2017 - 13h45");
$date_arr[1] = convert_date("Samedi 12 mars 2017 - 13h45");
$date_arr[2] = convert_date("Samedi 18 juin 2013 - 13h45");

print_r($date_arr);
arsort($date_arr);
echo "After sorting";
print_r($date_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! I obtain dates in this format : 2016-12-17T15:00:00+00:00
With this method and format, how would you sort the dates ? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to do that using the [array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: Yes I tried to do something like : `ksort($array_dates);`  but it didn't sort anything.

Comment: ksort() is used when you want to sort by key.. using asort() or arsort() 

It should work because the date is in ISO 8601 format.

Comment: `code` 

$date_arr[0] = convert_date("Samedi 14 janvier 2017 - 13h45");
$date_arr[1] = convert_date("Samedi 12 mars 2017 - 13h45");
$date_arr[2] = convert_date("Samedi 18 juin 2013 - 13h45");

print_r($date_arr);
arsort($date_arr);
echo "After sorting";
print_r($date_arr);

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127419/discussion-between-samay-and-ty-yt).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your last comment. The code is working fine now, thanks for all your help.